# How to calculate the days between 2 dates without 31st of any month

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponents

#### Main Goal:

I want to count wage based on 30days in every month

in month with 31 it should count max 30 days

```
let monthlyWage = someValue
let perDay : Double = Double(monthlyWage/30)
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from:startDateDay, to: currentDateDay)
let daysPassed = Double(components.day! + 1)
let componentsForStatement = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month], from: currentDateDay)
if ((componentsForStatement.month == 01) || 
    (componentsForStatement.month == 03) ||
    (componentsForStatement.month == 05) || 
    (componentsForStatement.month == 07) || 
    (componentsForStatement.month == 08) || 
    (componentsForStatement.month == 10) || 
    (componentsForStatement.month == 12)
   ) && componentsForStatement.day == 31 {
          daysPassed -= 1
        }
let currentMoney = Double(lround(perDay * daysPassed))
```

Comment: You might get better help if you update your question to include what you are actually trying to solve with this code. There's probably a better solution.

Comment: Thx, changed, may be this now will be better

Comment: i also still not don't understand your question. and what you try to do. i miss the definition for `daysPassed`.

Comment: you can short your `if` statement to: `if (componentsForStatement.day == 31 { daysPassed -= 1}` because in the other moths it never true for `.day == 31`

Comment: whats with the days in february?

Comment: please describe your big goal - why you need this code snippet?

Comment: @muescha I want to count wage based on 30days in every month

Comment: please add this info to your question. why not just count the months as 30 days. please add your wage formula how you like to calculate.

Comment: startDate / endDate is any Date in Any Month?

Comment: @muescha added to code: because I want to refresh data perDay

Comment: it is a very asked question at google: https://www.google.de/webhp?q=calculate+wage+30+days+month

Comment: can you add examples for startDate and endDate?

Comment: @muescha startDate is chosen from datePicker, so it can be any and Current is Today

Comment: why not count the months between the dates (adjust if the dates on the first or last date in month) and multiply it with monthly salary and in the first month and the last month count just the working days? maybe in your country exists some rules how to calculate the salary (most answers in google search are from india - maybe they have a detailed labour rule about how to calculate the salary)

Comment: @muescha for example startDate: 31 December, currentDate: 31 January, it should count dayPassed = 30

Comment: here (http://user.hrpro.hk/user-guide-hrpro/what-is-30-days-average-for-daily-salary-based-on-in-payroll-module-setup ) i found this rule for salary: When 30 Days Average is selected in Daily Salary based on, the daily salary will calculated as:

For complete worked month: Monthly Salary / 30 ...
For incomplete worked month: Monthly Salary / 30 x RoundToInteger (30 x Days between start date and end date / no. of days of the months)

Comment: but you have always only one month diff? it is very unclear until you write the hole question or real live examples and not only a detailed question.

Comment: you like to calculate the total salary for: startDate = 10.Jan.2016 / endDate = 17.feb.2017?

Comment: @muescha I also wanted to use Round, but it can be not accurate enough, need to check, thank you for this rule
Diff can be various from 90 to 150 days, any number

Comment: give some examples of startDate and endDate and the expected salary (what should be calculated)

Comment: start date is always first day of month or andy date in the month?

Comment: dates like you said: 10.01.16 and 12.05.17, salary 3000, per day 100
So 122 days(not counting 31st and february +2) and totally 12200

Comment: @muescha start of contract and end could be any Date

Comment: in feb 16 it is only +1 (max 29 in feb 2016)

Comment: @muescha mistake, i thought about 10.01.17

Comment: 10.01.16 is counted as 20, 21, 22 days? because the employee worked also on the 10th

Comment: please update you original question with the new informations you give as answers. this helps other users too for the answer of the questions

Comment: so if he start on 30.jan 2017 then he worked 2 days (30 + 31) but should get payed 1 day?

Comment: i updated your question from your answers to my questions

Comment: then the total days should be 123

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136765/discussion-on-question-by-o-soap-how-to-calculate-the-days-between-2-dates-witho).

Answer (score 0):

(i updated the original question to the answers in comments)

in 2016

```
10.01.16 Jan ?? (max 31) 21 
   02.16 Feb +1 (max 29) 30
   03.16 Mar -1 (max 31) 30
   04.16 Apr +0 (max 30) 30
12.05.16 May +0 (max 31) 12
```

or in 2017

```
10.01.17 Jan ?? (max 31) 21 
   02.17 Feb +2 (max 28) 30
   03.17 Mar -1 (max 31) 30
   04.17 Apr +0 (max 30) 30
12.05.17 May +0 (max 31) 12
```

i implemented it in this way:

- check if start before end
- check if in same month -> calculate worked days with average
- otherwise: extract first month / month between / last month and add together

here is the code:

```
import Foundation

func day(_ dateString:String) -> Date {
    let dateStringFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let d = dateStringFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    return Date(timeInterval:0, since:d)
}


func createDate(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) -> Date {
    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = day
    dateComponents.month = month
    dateComponents.year = year
    return userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
}

func printDate(date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

func check(from startDate: String, to endDate: String, expected: Int){
    let days = daysBeetweenMax30(from: day(startDate), to: day(endDate))
    let ok = expected == days ? "OK" : "!!"
    let error = expected == days ? "" : "(current: \(days) expected: \(expected))"
    print(" \(ok): \(startDate) -> \(endDate) => \(days)  \(error)")
}

func daysInMonth(of date: Date) -> Int {
    let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    return userCalendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date)!.count
}

func setDayInDate(day: Int, of date: Date) -> Date {
    let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    var components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date)
    components.day = day
    return userCalendar.date(from: components)!
}

func daysBeetweenMax30(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) -> Int {

//    print("start: \(printDate(date: startDate)) ende:\(printDate(date: endDate))")

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    // check order
    guard userCalendar.compare(startDate, to: endDate, toGranularity: .day) != .orderedDescending else {
        print("startDate should be before endDate")
        return 0
    }

    // check if in same month
    guard userCalendar.compare(startDate, to: endDate, toGranularity: .month) != .orderedSame else {
        let components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day], from:startDate, to: endDate)

        let days = (components.day ?? 0) + 1
        let calculatedDays = Double(30.0 * Double(days) / Double(daysInMonth(of: startDate)))
        let averageDays = Int(calculatedDays.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))

//        print("same month")
//        print("daysInMonth: \(daysInMonth(of: startDate))")
//        print("days: \(days)")
//        print( "calculatedDays: \(calculatedDays)")

        return averageDays

//        maximum 30 days - but need to adjust for february .....
//        return min((components.day ?? 0) + 1,30)

    }


    let startDateEnd = setDayInDate(day: daysInMonth(of: startDate), of: startDate)
    let startMonthDays = daysBeetweenMax30(from: startDate, to: startDateEnd)

    let endDateStart = setDayInDate(day: 1, of: endDate)
    let endMonthDays = daysBeetweenMax30(from: endDateStart, to: endDate)

    let components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.month], from:startDateEnd, to: endDateStart)
    let monthBetween = components.month ?? 0
//    print("monthBetween: \(monthBetween)")
    return startMonthDays + monthBetween*30 + endMonthDays
}
```

check:

```
check(from: "2017-05-01", to: "2017-04-01", expected: 0)
print("----")
check(from: "2017-05-01", to: "2017-05-10", expected: 10)
check(from: "2017-05-05", to: "2017-05-09", expected: 5)
check(from: "2017-05-16", to: "2017-05-20", expected: 5)
check(from: "2017-05-30", to: "2017-05-31", expected: 2)
print("----")
check(from: "2017-05-01", to: "2017-05-31", expected: 30)
check(from: "2017-02-01", to: "2017-02-28", expected: 30)
print("----")
check(from: "2017-02-01", to: "2017-02-27", expected: 29)
check(from: "2017-02-01", to: "2017-02-02", expected: 2)
check(from: "2017-02-01", to: "2017-02-13", expected: 14)
check(from: "2017-02-01", to: "2017-02-14", expected: 15)
check(from: "2017-02-01", to: "2017-02-18", expected: 19)
check(from: "2017-02-26", to: "2017-02-28", expected: 3)
print("----")
check(from: "2017-05-30", to: "2017-06-02", expected: 2+2)
check(from: "2017-02-26", to: "2017-03-03", expected: 3+3)
check(from: "2017-05-30", to: "2017-07-02", expected: 2+1*30+2)
check(from: "2017-05-30", to: "2017-08-02", expected: 2+2*30+2)
print("----")
check(from: "2017-01-10", to: "2017-01-31", expected: 21)
check(from: "2017-02-01", to: "2017-02-28", expected: 30)
check(from: "2017-03-01", to: "2017-03-31", expected: 30)
check(from: "2017-04-01", to: "2017-04-30", expected: 30)
check(from: "2017-05-01", to: "2017-05-12", expected: 12)
print("----")
check(from: "2017-01-10", to: "2017-05-12", expected: 123)
check(from: "2017-01-10", to: "2017-05-12", expected: 21+3*30+12)
check(from: "2016-01-10", to: "2016-05-12", expected: 123) // 2016 with leap year
print("    ----")
check(from: "2016-01-10", to: "2017-05-12", expected: 21+(12+3)*30+12)
```

result:

```
startDate should be before endDate
OK: 2017-05-01 -> 2017-04-01 => 0  
----
OK: 2017-05-01 -> 2017-05-10 => 10  
OK: 2017-05-05 -> 2017-05-09 => 5  
OK: 2017-05-16 -> 2017-05-20 => 5  
OK: 2017-05-30 -> 2017-05-31 => 2  
----
OK: 2017-05-01 -> 2017-05-31 => 30  
OK: 2017-02-01 -> 2017-02-28 => 30  
----
OK: 2017-02-01 -> 2017-02-27 => 29  
OK: 2017-02-01 -> 2017-02-02 => 2  
OK: 2017-02-01 -> 2017-02-13 => 14  
OK: 2017-02-01 -> 2017-02-14 => 15  
OK: 2017-02-01 -> 2017-02-18 => 19  
OK: 2017-02-26 -> 2017-02-28 => 3  
----
OK: 2017-05-30 -> 2017-06-02 => 4  
OK: 2017-02-26 -> 2017-03-03 => 6  
OK: 2017-05-30 -> 2017-07-02 => 34  
OK: 2017-05-30 -> 2017-08-02 => 64  
----
OK: 2017-01-10 -> 2017-01-31 => 21  
OK: 2017-02-01 -> 2017-02-28 => 30  
OK: 2017-03-01 -> 2017-03-31 => 30  
OK: 2017-04-01 -> 2017-04-30 => 30  
OK: 2017-05-01 -> 2017-05-12 => 12  
----
OK: 2017-01-10 -> 2017-05-12 => 123  
OK: 2017-01-10 -> 2017-05-12 => 123  
OK: 2016-01-10 -> 2016-05-12 => 123  
----
OK: 2016-01-10 -> 2017-05-12 => 483
```

Comment: pls check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @muescha ideas I make this code good for not counting 31day in month:

```
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from:startContractDateDay, to: currentDateDay)
var daysPassed = Double(components.day! + 1)
var startDay = startContractDateDay
while startDay <= currentDateDay {
    let startDayComponent = calendar.component(.day, from: startDay)
    if startDayComponent == 31 {
       daysPassed -= 1
    }
startDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDay)!
}
```

Comment: in first month if it starts in the middle of a month then you cut off one day if it  is in a 31day month. there is no rule for the february implemented

Comment: also a problem is if the start and end day is in the same moth of a 31th day month

Comment: @muescha I checked on practise, it counts perfect.
For february it is just the same logic +=2 for 28 February and then -=1 for 29 February if it is present

Comment: but not in your code snippet - i don't see the feb calculation there